# Why am I having this database issue?

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I am working on a Python/Django project, and we need to use two databases. Following the documentation I added a second database like this:

```
DATABASE_URL = os.getenv('DATABASE_URL', 'postgres://*******:********@aws-us-***********:*****/*****')
CURRENCIES_URL = os.getenv('CURRENCIES_URL', 'postgres://*******:********@aws-us-***********:*****/*****')

DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.parse(DATABASE_URL),
    'currencies': dj_database_url.parse(CURRENCIES_URL)
}
```

The parse() method returns the data in the format the object is expecting.

Then, I have this code:

```
currencies = connection['currencies'].cursor()
```

Basically this allows me to run custom SQL code on the database, by returning its cursor and storing it in `currencies`

However when running this code I get this in the console:

```
url(r'^', include('btcmag.urls', namespace="btcmag")),
  File "/Users/john/.virtualenvs/btcmag/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/john/btcmag/btcmag/urls.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/Users/john/btcmag/btcmag/views.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .apis import getTrendingArticles, getTickers, getCurrency, getHistory
  File "/Users/john/btcmag/btcmag/apis.py", line 9, in <module>
    currencies = connection['currencies'].cursor()
TypeError: 'DefaultConnectionProxy' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Some clarification:

- When I run just `currencies = connection.cursor()` it uses the `default` database and works just fine, which tells me it's not the connection module
- If I switch `currencies` and `default` in the databases settings it works also fine - running `currencies = connection.cursor()` - by using the Currencies DB as default. So the DB is not the issue either.

What could be causing the issue here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a small but fatal typo in your code. It should be `django.db.connections` instead of your `connection` (you have not specified where that comes from).

Quoting from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

> If you are using more than one database, you can use
>   django.db.connections to obtain the connection (and cursor) for a
>   specific database. `django.db.connections` is a dictionary-like object
>   that allows you to retrieve a specific connection using its alias:
>
> ```
> from django.db import connections
> cursor = connections['my_db_alias'].cursor()
> # Your code here...
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can't access `connection` using bracket notation.

Perhaps this will work:

```
currencies = DATABASES['currencies'].cursor()
```

Comment: Actually, your answer made me realize that there was another module called "connections" and when using that I was able to connect. My issue was that I was using "connection" instead. Perhpas you want to rephrase the answer and I will mark it as the correct one